# Split markdown by each section using ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this markdown as string:

```
# section 1\n\n
any type of valid markdown text. /notations here\n 
Sample text for testing:
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789 _+-.,!@$%^&*();\/|<>"'
12345 -98.7 3.141 .6180 9,000 +42
555.123.4567    +1-(800)-555-2468
foo@demo.net    bar.ba@test.co.uk
www.demo.com    http://foo.co.uk/
http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar
https://mediatemple.net
- list 1
- list 2
[www.asdf.com](some description)

## sec 1.1\n blah\n
# header 2\n\n
## 2.1\n\n
### 2.2\n
# some_section\n
## 3.1\n\n
```

I would like to split the string by section, eg the output should be a list of 3 entries of string. The first entry should be '# section 1\n\n ## 1.1\n blah\n'.

The regex i'm using is /[^#]# [\s\S]+?(?=#)/ . How do I match a string without ' #' at the end? And my regex is matching the whole string instead of the output i need.

Sample at http://regexr.com/3ev83 . Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `/^# section\s+\d+.*?(?=^# section\s+\d|\z)/m`. Or `/^# section\s*\d+.*(?:\R(?!# section\s+\d).*)*/`

Comment: I think the splitting approaches below should work for you. Please accept the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
string.split(/(?=^# )/)
```

And if you want to split at any heading from `#` through `###`

```
string.split(/(?=^#+ )/)
```

How does this work?

- `^` matches the begin of the line
- `(?=...)` is a lookahead match
- No need to match line endings

Comment: Good one! Perhaps `/(?=# section\s+\d+\n$)/`?

Comment: Is there a way to generalise the header for the section(eg # some_header)? I tried [^#]# [\s\S]+?(?=#) .

Comment: Not sure I understand, updated with a variant that matches any heading.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [slice_before](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) instead of a big regex :

```
markup = "# section 1\n\n
## 1.1\n
blah\n
# section 2\n\n
## 2.1\n\n
### 2.2\n
# section 3\n
## 3.1\n\n "

p markup.each_line.slice_before(/# section \d+/).map(&:join)
#=> ["# section 2\n\n\n## 1.1\n\nblah\n\n", "# section 2\n\n\n## 2.1\n\n\n### 2.2\n\n", "# section 3\n\n## 3.1\n\n "]
```

If you want to generalise the method for any header, you can just use :

```
p markup.each_line.slice_before(/^# /).map(&:join)
```

If you want to iterate over every line in each section, you can remove join :

```
markup.each_line.slice_before(/^# /).each do |section|
  section.each do |line|
    # do something with line
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to generalise the header for the section(eg # some_header)? I tried [^#]# [\s\S]+?(?=#) but it is not splitting the section.